# How does Arduino memorize the last bytes from Bluetooth HC-05?

Tags: arduino-nano, eeprom

I have made a home automation project.

Description: Light on, off through HC-05 Bluetooth module and my Android app. The problem is when the power is gone, the system stops, that's OK. After that, when the power comes back, the system remains off, as because of no storage of the value.

Please any one help me, that how to store Bluetooth data on EEPROM on Arduino. My simple code looks like...

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
#define ledPin 7
int state = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Default communication rate of the Bluetooth module
}

void loop() {

  if(Serial.available() > 0){ // Checks whether data is comming from the serial port
    state = Serial.read(); // Reads the data from the serial port
  }

  if (state == '0') {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // Turn LED OFF
    Serial.println("LED: OFF"); // Send back, to the phone, the String "LED: ON"
    state = 0;
  }
  else if (state == '1') {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    Serial.println("LED: ON");;
    state = 0;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Don't shout next time! Also format the code correctly.

Comment: Have you tried to use the EEPROM examples from the Arduino IDE? There is a library for using the EEPROM. Do you have any specific problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Sir you didn't used EEPROM functions, you just initialized them. For example

- [`EEPROM.read();`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/EEPROMRead)
- [`EEPROM.write();`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/EEPROMWrite)

if you use these function then your issue will be solved out..